# What does the abbreviation "gem." mean?

Tags: abbreviation

What does the abbreviation "gem." mean?  E.g. :

> Leistungen im Bereich Finanzbuchhaltung gem. bei Leistungsbeschreibung.

Comment: And not to mention it is bad style, cause there is no sense in shorten a word from only 5 to 3 letters.

Comment: It's not so bad style when used in the comments field of a bank transfer. Neither *ä* nor *ß* can be used there and there is little space. Using *gem.* instead of *gemaess* saves three letters and makes it even look better.

Answer (score 14):

There's a list of common meanings of the abbreviation "gem." [here](http://abkuerzungen.woxikon.de/abkuerzung/gem..php), but none of them quite fit into your sentence, and I'm not aware of any word starting with gem- that would make perfect grammatical and contextual sense here, either.

I strongly suspect the "bei" slipped in by accident, and what they mean to say is "Leistungen im Bereich Finanzbuchhaltung **gemäß** Leistungsbeschreibung", i.e. "Services in financial accounting **according to** the description of services."

Comment: Agreed. Two remarks: The link you provide seems not too reliable; they offer _gemä_ instead of _gemäß_. And I think it's worth pointing out that it's slightly ridiculous to abbreviate _gemäß_ by replacing _äß_ with a dot.

Comment: "bei" could also be an accidental truncation of "beiliegender", which means "attached".

Comment: @Hendrik: Yeah, it's not a great list, but at least it gives you some idea of what options there are. I tried to find a more comprehensive list, but had no success. Gem. is a very common abbreviation of gemäß, although I agree that it doesn't save much space.

Answer (score 3):

It means "according to". 
You can stick 'gem.' into an online dictionary like http://dict.tu-chemnitz.de/ and it will come up showing that gem. is short for gemäß which means "according to" or "in accordance with".

Answer (score 1):

Usually "gem." would mean "gemäß", "according to".  In this case it does not fit the grammar because of the spurious "bei" following it.

A somewhat remote possibility would be "gemeinhin", "generally".  However, the connection between "Leistungen" and "Leistungsbeschreibung" is so obvious that in this case it appears quite more likely that the "bei" got in spuriously and that "gemäß" was intended.